# Android databinding : how can I bind a layout identifier to include

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to include a layout with databinding.

I want to pass the id from java to my layout, using an `enum`, but I cant seem to find out the right syntax.

Here is my Fragment class with the `enum` and the `onCreateView()`:

```
private enum TYPE{
    A(R.layout.fragment_item_A),
    B(R.layout.fragment_item_B),
    C(R.layout.fragment_item_C);

    public final int id;
    TYPE(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    private int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    this.type = TYPE.A;
    FragmentItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
    tmpView = binding.getRoot();
    binding.setType(type);
    //...
    return tmpView;
}
```

I want to inflate `R.layout.fragment_item` and make it include `R.layout.fragment_item_A` (or another Type).

Here is my unsuccessful attempt in my R.layout.fragment_item XML file:

```
<data>
    <variable name="type" type="com.dan.myapp.fragments.MyFragmentClass.TYPE"/>
...
</data>
<include layout="@{type.id}" <!-- layout="@layout/fragment_item_A"-->
         android:id="@+id/included_item"/>
```

**How should I write the binding in the include ?**

PS : maybe the answer is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273517/databinding-how-to-get-resource-by-dynamic-id) or in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809290/set-drawable-resource-id-in-androidsrc-for-imageview-using-data-binding-in-andr), but I didn't find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can't do that. Data Binding requires the layout at compile type so that it can determine types for passing variables and such.

Instead, I think you might do it like this:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <ViewStub android:layout="@layout/fragment_item_a"
              android:visibility="@{type == Type.A ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" .../>
    <ViewStub android:layout="@layout/fragment_item_b"
              android:visibility="@{type == Type.B ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" .../>
    <ViewStub android:layout="@layout/fragment_item_c"
              android:visibility="@{type == Type.C ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Too bad, but I guess you're right. Though, I use your code but with only one ViewStub and change the layout programmatically. Works like a charm. Thanks !