# ButterKnife @BindString equivalent in Android data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, butterknife

In my source code I have the following `ButterKnife` annotation:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindString(R2.string.settings_progress)
    String progressText;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now I've decided to switch to Android Data Binding.

What would the equivalent be if I use Android data binding?

Should I declare a variable inside `<data></data>` tags in the activities XML file?

Comment: see: https://zarah.dev/2016/07/19/using-resource-ids-in-data-binding.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273517/databinding-how-to-get-resource-by-dynamic-id, might help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

The basic usage is like this:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text).apply {
    text = viewModel.userName
}
```

Or in XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.myapp.data.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:text="@{viewmodel.userName}" />
</layout>
```

Both of these approaches require using a ViewModel to connect the binding. However, I believe with the first approach you can bind to any observable property, (not 100% sure about the details on that).